# ListItem: Set Item-level Permissions with a few exceptions

Tags: permissions, list-item

I have created a custom ListItem in VS with a custom content template. I have enabled set Item-level Permissions. It is now only possible to see your own items in the list. Also it is only possible to edit your own items.

I would like to implement some logic or change some settings, so it will be possible for users in usergroup "SomeUserGroup" can see all the items in the list and can edit all the items in the list. Also from items created by other users.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create your own permissions group by going through site collection -->site actions -->  site permissions --> add a permission level -->associate those permissions to your list.

Comment: But I am looking for some solution where I can use item-level permission for all normal users, except for the users in the usergroup "SomeCustomGroup". Thes users in usergroup "SomeCustomGroup" can see all items in this list and can edit all these items.

I hope you understand me.

Comment: IIRC, if you give the SomeCustomGroup the permission Manage List permission in your list (don't remember exactly the level needed) they'll see all the items in the list.

Comment: It works If I give the "SomeCustomGroup" the following permissions: Design - Can view, add, update, delete, approve, and customize.

The problem is now that all users in this group can also customize the list. Thats not what I want, because they are normal users, with 1 extra permission: can see all items in the list.

Comment: I have created my own permission level and selected "Manage Lists". But this permission gives my users in the usergroup too much permissions. With this permission it is also possible to go to the List settings and change columns and other stuff.. Thats not what I want. Is there some other solution? In c# code is also ok.

Comment: KHA, By creating a UI based Permission level(based on my above comments) you can give whatever kind of permissions you want to assign to groups or users mostly like you can control a user group to just view, add, edit an items in a list but not to delete them.....something like that based on your Req's

Comment: I have created my own permission level and selected "Manage Lists". But this permission gives my users in the usergroup too much permissions. With this permission it is also possible to go to the List settings and change columns and other stuff.. Thats not what I want. Is there some other solution? In c# code is also ok.